# ZeroMQ subscriber fails to initialize using 1000+ publishers

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq

I am trying to evaluate ZeroMQ for a larger monitoring and data gathering system. On a smaller scale everything works nice but stepping up the load and scale a bit seems tricky.

Right now I am using a C# wrapper (clrzmq, 3.0.0-rc1) to create both a publisher and a subscriber application. I am binding the Publisher socket (1 socket, 1 context) to 1000 endpoints (localhost + a range of ports) and let the Subscriber applications socket (again 1 socket, 1 context) bind to the publisher endpoints.

This sometimes works, and sometimes not (I guess it relates to the max number of sockets handled by the process somehow). It seems to depend on in which order I start the applications but I cannot tell for sure. The only thing I see is nasty SEHExceptions, containing no details at all. If I create simple console applications I sometimes see low level C++ Asserts like:

- Assertion failed: fds.size () <= FD_SETSIZE (......\src\select.cpp:70)
- Assertion failed: Permission denied (......\src\signaler.cpp:281)
- Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer (......\src\signaler.cpp:124)

Not very helpful to me. In the C# wrapper, the Context creation fails. It does not even get a chance to begin connecting to or even creating sockets. I would expect low level ZeroMQ errors to be handled by throwing exceptions, maybe I just have not understood how to deal with errors yet.

**The questions I have right now is:**

- How do I create a (somewhat) realistic test setup to simulate 1000 separate publishers on a single machine (in real world 1 publisher = 1 machine) and a couple of Subscribers on Another machine, all using C#. Is that even possible?
- More importantly, how do I trap ZeroMQ errors in C# code to be able to understand what goes wrong?

Since ZeroMQ seems pretty stable and mature I have a hard time believing 1000 publishers should be a problem to handle. However, I need better error support than currently available (unless I completely missed something here) in order to use ZeroMQ over C#.

**Update:**

After diggin into the source, I end up with a `zmq_assert(...)` leading to `RaiseException (0x40000015, EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE, 1, extra_info);`. This will abruptly terminate the application after dumping the original assert statement to the console. This seems a bit harsh, but may well be the best option given that it is really unrecoverable. However, a somewhat better error message would not hurt. Not everyone knows what `fds.size () <= FD_SETSIZE` means. The comment in the source gives some clues, would be nice to have that comment in the error message. Anyway, given that my application is not a console app, this just leaves me with an unhandled SEHException, which does not seem to contain even the assert statement or line/file info. I wonder how many other bugs I will create that will result in other similar cryptical errors.

Comment: See also: https://zeromq.jira.com/browse/LIBZMQ-574

Comment: @tjrobinson Ah, that looks nice, thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default FD_SETSIZE is 1024 (defined in the MSVC libzmq project), so you will hit this about half-way through your test case. The other asserts tumble on from that.

Increase this in your libzmq project, to 4K or 8K, and things should work better.

As for the assert() call, it's too brutal on Windows, for sure. On Linux this gives a decent stack dump and enough information to trace the problem. Feel free to improve the assert macro so that it does something smarter, e.g. launch the debugger. In any case if you hit an assert you can't reasonably continue.

Asserting when the FD set is full, well, that could be handled better. If you know anything about C/C++, feel free to take a look at the code. We do depend on peoples' patches.

Also, if you feel 1024 is too small, feel free to raise this in the project and send us the patch.

Answer (score 3):

After looking into this a bit more, it seems the default number of sockets are set to 1024. The C# wrapper has a property on the `Context` object that should be able to change this setting but it is not working, at least not as expected. Also, the native `zmqlib` does not have this setting on the context object.

Running a setup like in the description does not seem possible, at least not using the `clrzmq` C# ZeroMQ wrapper. I solved it by running 500 publishers on a separate machine and another 500 plus 1000 subscribers on another machine. This worked nice without any errors.

The other topic is also a bit disappointing. When the maximum number of sockets are reached, ZeroMQ simply throws an uncatchable exception causing the application to crash abruptly. This is a fail fast approach, avoiding any further data/state corruption but unfortunatly also leaves very few clues to what happend that caused the application to die. Judging from other posts, it seems very hard to gather data for post-mortem when this happens. Catching the exception in the C# code seems impossible or very hard, and hooking into the stdout to capture the printed assert also seems very hard to achieve (if we are not running from a command prompt, in which case the assert message is printed just before the application dies).

All-in-all, this makes low-level trouble shooting and post-mortem analysis in a non-console C# setting very hard when ZeroMQ terminates via the zmq_assert(...) call. Hopefully this was an extreme case. Not all failure modes seems to cause termination in this abrupt way.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty look into this problem suggest that you're creating too many socket connections for your computer. Check out this [link on the max number of sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN. The error's you are getting look suspiciously relevant enough for this to be a possible source of your error.

To be honest, having 1000 separate publishers seems like you are tackling the problem a little incorrectly for using zmq. Why not have 1 publisher and use 'namespaces' and have the subscribers SUBSCRIBE to what it needs to split out what messages subscribers get.

Comment: Yes, 1000 Publishers on a single box is just for development and simulation. It is likely that it will fail, although I would like to use such a setup in development. The bigger problem however is the lack of good error handling/reporting. As of now the application simply crashes without much extra information when the socket limit is reached. I would expect something more useful.

Comment: IMO, I would rather the application crash than silently fail. Are you going to have 1000 publishers (meaning 1000 separate boxes/cpus/heads) in your production environment? Any reason you cannot do what I suggest and cut the entire number down to 1 or just a few and implement some smart filtering?

Comment: Agreed, I want the crash, but with some more clues to what Went wrong. Logging, exceptions, error codes, whatever. In the production Environment we will have up to 1000 separate boxes, each publishing data, gathered by one or more servers (using subscription sockets) so unfortunately I cannot cut it down to a single Publisher. Not for scaling tests at least. But the main problem for me is missing error details right now, the rest is just convenience.

Comment: Jakob, I think the assert macros on Windows can be improved to give you what you need.